# How do I debug with Google App Engine PHP?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Here's the scenario.
I test my PHP web app locally.
Everything works fine.
I deploy to Google App Engine.
When I try to use it I get a white page.
Something is broken somewhere.

So I look into the logs and see this:
    A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request,     causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for     the next request to your application. (Error code 204)

Nearly completely useless.
No explanation of what error code 204 is.

So I'd like to add some logging code or something to try to figure out what the problem is so that I can debug it.

I see from the doc that the way to do this is to add syslog() calls.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/logs/

Ok. Cool.
So I add some to my code.
I redeploy and look at the logs again.
None of my log events are being written.

So the existing logging data is useless and I don't appear to be able to do any logging myself.
How do I debug?

Comment: Could you file an issue at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?q=Language%3DPHP thanks.

Comment: OK. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11904&thanks=11904&ts=1429918953

Answer (score 0):

If you have a debugger that is compatible with the XDebug debugger, and you have the xdebug module installed, it is possible to use XDebug with the Development Server to debug your local application. And you can look at [Local debugging with XDebug](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/tools/devserver#PHP_Local_debugging_with_XDebug) for more details about debugging your local application.